# What is the benefit of creating good URLs (using slug), instead of unique id like youtube?

Tags: laravel, seo

> MY Question without code so pls bear with me :)

Now in Laravel, you use for links of our app the slug to arrange the links of app. and youtube uses some letters and numbers I don't know what it is for a video! like `i0b2ejl7tXM`

So what the difference in **SEO** if we use the unique code like youtube and we use the slug which is the name of the post?

Answer (score 1):

From what I've taken from this [article](https://moz.com/beginners-guide-to-seo) and from my experience, of course it has a difference. The difference, a good URL will increase your post ranks in search engine. But, please keep in mind that SEO isn't just it. Please take a look at this good diagram.

[image: SEO Diagram]

Comment: So what's your recommend about this situation?

Comment: @ahmed It depends about what you're building. If you're building site that expect much with SEO ranks, of course you should consider use a good URLs. Youtube isn't a site that expect much with SEO ranks.

Comment: Fyi, Youtube is one of Google platform. So, I believe Youtube will always has good SEO ranks, no matter how Youtube looks like in google search engine.

Comment: That's confusing me! so the good slug is better ^^

Comment: Yup, good URLs (slug, or something like that) is better. Don't forget to accept my answer if you believe it's answering your question. :')

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function to generate and decode strings for your routes.

Routes:

```
Route::get(/'{code}', 'YourController@yourMethod');
```

Controller:

```
public function yourMethod(Request $request, $code)
    {
        $decodedValue = decodingFunction($code)
        ...
    }
```